# Creating video from images produces black screen video for certain image formats

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using below command to create video from images.The command works fine for most images but for png images the video created cannot be played and I just get a black screen.

```
 String[]  command = new String[]{"-y", "-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", src.getAbsolutePath(), "-vsync", "vfr", "-vf", "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2", dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

Here destination file path has mp4 format..
Whats wrong with my command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `format=yuv420p`. When given RGB input and output as MP4, ffmpeg chooses a pixel format not compatible with a lot of players.

Use

```
 String[]  command = new String[]{"-y", "-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", src.getAbsolutePath(), "-vsync", "vfr", "-vf", "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,format=yuv420p", dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

Comment: Did not work for me, hoped it helped someone else